# How to make partially coloured Chapter Title to appear only in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, color, chapters

I am trying to use the following command

```
\chapter [Introduction {\color{red}(estimated pages 7 -- 10)}] {Introduction}
```

to make a **partially colored chapter title to appear only in the TOC** of a monograph being written using `\documentclass{book}` (that is, the word **Introduction** should be **Black**, however, the **rest** should appear in **Red**). But this code is always giving compilation error although I have used the required packages **`sectsty`** and **`xcolor`**. I found that the **`\color`** command is causing the problem when placed in the **short title box** of the `\chapter [short title] {title}` command.

Minimal Working document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[labelsep=space,tableposition=top]{caption}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage    

\chapter[Introduction {\protect\color{red}(7 -- 10 pages)}]{Introduction}  
%Title of the First Chapter

\section[Section 1   {\protect\color{red} 1 --2 pages}]{Section 1}

\section[Section 2  {\protect\color{red} 1 --2 pages}]{Section 2}

\chapter[Chapter 2 {\protect\color{red}(7 -- 10 pages)}]{Chapter 2}  
%Title of the second Chapter

\section[Section 1   {\protect\color{red} 1 --2 pages}]{Section 1}

\section[Section 2  {\protect\color{red} 1 --2 pages}]{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would be grateful if anyone can help me out...

Comment: Did you try `{\protect\color{red}...}` instead? Also, it would be a lot easier if you provided a minimal working example (like described [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=606)).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I have tried it but it is not also working. I have provided the minimal working code, could you please run in your own machine and help me out? Maybe the \color command is causing conflict with some other packages...

Comment: Oh, the problem is a totally different one... Forget about the `\protect` (`\color` is already defined with a protection mechanism), the issue is the `\MakeUppercase` for page titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you posted your MWE, I realised that the issue is not the missing `\protect` (in fact `\color` is defined as `\protect\color␣` with a space in the macro name of the second `\color` and that one contains the actual code). The issue is that in `book` the page headers contain the upper cased chapter title using `\MakeUppercase`. That turns the colour into `RED` and that isn't defined. There are several possible solutions to this.

- The easiest: define `RED` to be an alias to `red` using `\colorlet{RED}{red}`.
- hide your `\color{red}` inside another protected macro, such as `\DeclareRobustCommand*\mytitlered{\color{red}}`.
- revert the effects of `\MakeUppercase` using the TeX primitve `\lowercase` on `\color{red}`

The following shows all three alternatives:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelsep=space,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{duckuments} % dummy content

\DeclareRobustCommand*\mytitlecolor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage


\chapter[Introduction {\mytitlecolor(7 -- 10 pages)}]{Introduction}  
%Title of the First Chapter
\blindduck[full]
\blindduck[full]

\chapter[Chapter 2 {\lowercase{\color{red}}(7 -- 10 pages)}]{Chapter 2}
\blindduck[full]
\blindduck[full]

\colorlet{RED}{red}
\chapter[Chapter 2 {\color{red}(7 -- 10 pages)}]{Chapter 2}
\blindduck[full]
\blindduck[full]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. Sorry to say I'm still not able to make it. Could you please test my code in your machine?

Comment: @ParijatBhowmick see my new answer.

Comment: Thank you so much #Skillmon. It is working now. Thanks for your kind help...